# How data skew can be handled?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I've a two data sets, `A and B` and both are having same one column, named as `status`. Its a hypothetical situation to understand to have evenly split of data among partitions.

In both tables, `A and B`, values can `true or false`, 90% of data is as `true` in both tables, and data size we can thing of something which could create this skewness issue.

```
status
true
true
false
.
.
```

Table B

```
status
true
true
.
.
```

When I left join on status, it will not distribute data evenly, what salt technique I can add in this to have even distribute of data ?